# How to filter bounty questions in SO app for Android

Tags: feature-request, android-app

In the SO app for android, I can't see an option to filter questions that has an open bounty.

[image]

It would be nice if this feature is available.

Comment: Is there any problem with this feature request?

Comment: It's also lacking the options "Hot", "Unanswered (newest)" and "Unanswered (my tags)", which are available in the SE app. I can't think of any reason why these options (including "Featured") shouldn't exist in the SO app.